# Mysql syntax error with stored procedure (workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Ok so this is my current code

```
delimiter //

Create procedure addFish(in_color varchar(45), in_pattern varchar(45))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ZenFish
(`ZenColorsID`,`Pattern`, `Hatched`     )
VALUES
(
(select idZenColors from ZenColors where ColorName = in_color),
in_pattern,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
END

delimiter ;
```

It does NOTHING when I press run in mysql workbench. Before I added the delimiter marks it at least gave me a syntax error. Adding delimiter lines seems to be what everyone else on stackoverflow was told to do with this problem, so I did it and now... just nothing happens when I press run, or select it all and press run, or run this statement. De nada.

Comment: What happens if you run it on the MySQL console? Connect to the server manually, and run `mysql` from the command line, and try executing that command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have small issue on your end tag

```
delimiter $$

Create procedure addFish(in_color varchar(45), in_pattern varchar(45))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ZenFish
(`ZenColorsID`,`Pattern`, `Hatched`     )
VALUES
(
(select idZenColors from ZenColors where ColorName = in_color),
in_pattern,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
END$$

delimiter ;
```

try this

Comment: try this and let me know

Comment: Hallelujah! It needed to be "delimiter $$" not "delimiter$$" but it is working now, thank you.